# How to access Facebook event info in iOS?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-events

I am trying to access the facebook event info of the user. I am currently trying to do something like:

```
[[delegate facebook] requestWithGraphPath:@"me/event/name" andDelegate:self];
```

But that gives me an error:

```
Err message: (null)
Err code: 10000
```

I have already integrated FBConnect into xcode and logged in the user. I also have this line of code:

```
if (![facebook isSessionValid]) {
    NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                            @"user_events",
                            nil];
    [facebook authorize:permissions];
    [permissions release];
}
```

in my application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: delegate method.

I want to get all the names of the user's events. How exactly would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try using just "me/events" as the graph path. ie.

```
[[delegate facebook] requestWithGraphPath:@"me/events" andDelegate:self];
```

**Edit:**

In the response method, do something like the below to process the result

```
NSArray *events = [result objectForKey:@"data"];
for ( NSDictionary *eventData in events ) {
    NSString * eventId = [eventData objectForKey:@"id"];
    NSString * eventName = [eventData objectForKey:@"name"];
}
```

Comment: How once I have the events how do I get the information about them. Like the name, start_time, etc.

Comment: The basic information for the event will be included in the JSON response of that request.  For the full details you can simply take the id of the event and use that as the request path.

Comment: Check out the documentation here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

Comment: I am trying to use this code `NSString *test;
 test = [result objectForKey:@"id"];
 NSLog(@"test = %@", test);`

Comment: inside the request:didLoad: method and the NSLog prints out `test = (null)` How do I get the info once inside the method. Also what if there is more than one event

Comment: I added code to the answer to describe how to get the id for each event returned.  You can simply NSLog out the result to get an idea of what is contained in it.

Comment: The NSArray doesnt contain anything. I used an NSLog `NSLog(@"%@", [events count]);` and it printed out (null). I even tried switching `me/events` to just `me` or `me/friends` and it still prints out (null).